# Spring boot RestEasy Post method Expected :201 Actual :404

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, resteasy

I have a spring boot application which contains a RestEasy webservice created using @Service like:

```
@Path("/developers")
@Service
public interface DeveloperResource {
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
Response create(@RequestBody List<DeveloperDto> developers);
}
```

and I have the the according integration test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class DeveloperResourceTest {

    public static final String URI = "http://localhost:8080/developers";
    public static final DeveloperDto DEVELOPER = new DeveloperDto(null, "toto");
    public static final List<DeveloperDto> DEVELOPERS_COLLECTION = Collections.singletonList(DEVELOPER);
    public static final DeveloperEntity DEVELOPER_MAPPED_TO_ENTITY = DeveloperMapper.toEntity(DEVELOPER);
    public static final String DEVELOPER_COLLECTION_IN_JSON = "[{\"developerId\":null,\"developerName\":\"toto\",\"programmingLanguages\":null}]";


    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    DeveloperService service;

    @Mock
    private DeveloperResource tested;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private ObjectMapper mapperJson;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        tested=new DeveloperResourceImpl(service);
        mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
        mapperJson = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_create_a_developer_and_return_OK() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(service.save(DEVELOPER_MAPPED_TO_ENTITY)).thenReturn(Optional.of(DEVELOPER_MAPPED_TO_ENTITY));

        tested.create(DEVELOPERS_COLLECTION);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(URI)
                .content(DEVELOPER_COLLECTION_IN_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals(URI, response.getHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION));

    }
}
```

After the execution of the test I got:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected :201
>   Actual   :404

My questions are:

1. Is my integration test configuration apropriate?
2. Can we use MockMvc even if the created REST web service isn't created using @RestController or @Controller?.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post your application.properties?

Comment: Thank's for the reply, I don't have a properties file for the configuration because it's a spring boot auto configuration using:

"@SpringBootApplication"
"@ComponentScan"

I have application.yaml but it contains just the persistence configuration:
server port:8080
jpa hibernate auto
database URL

Answer (score 0):

@Service will not be recognized as a rest service. You should annotate it as @RestController on a class, actually implementing the create method.
see: [@Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use `MockMvc` to test an app that doesn’t use Spring MVC. RESTdocs has support for Rest Assured which works over HTTP so it doesn’t depend on the web stack.